# How can I call a lambda function from another lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the contrived class below with a method A() that contains two lambda functions, a1() and a2(). I'd like to be able to invoke a2 from inside a1. However, when I do so, (the second line inside a1), I get the error

*Error: variable “cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified”*

I don't understand this error message. What am I supposed to be capturing here? I understand that using **[this]** in the lambda definition gives me access to methods in class foo but I'm unclear as to how to do what I want.

Thanks in advance for setting me straight on this.

```
class foo
{
   void A()
   {
      auto a2 = [this]() -> int
      {
         return 1;
      };

      auto  a1 = [this]() -> int
         {
            int result;
            result = a2();
            return result;
         };

      int i = a1();
      int j = a2();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to capture `a2` in order to odr-use `a2` within the body of `a1`. Simply capturing `this` does not capture `a2`; capturing `this` only allows you to use the non-static members of the enclosing class. If you expect `a2` to be captured by default, you need to specify either `=` or `&` as the capture-default.

```
[this, &a2]  // capture a2 by reference
[this, &]    // capture all odr-used automatic local variables by reference, including a2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response but I'm still unclear.   While  [this, &a2] does work,  [this, &] does not.

Comment: @David - It may be useful to specify a compiler and version.  In VS 2017, for instance, it has to be `[&, this]` although the error message is quite clear.

Comment: @zzxyz .   I'm using XCode 9.x  and you're absolutely right, you have to put the & before 'this'.  Now everything works --- thanks so much to both you and Brian

Comment: More specifically, The reason why capturing `this` does not also capture `a2` is because `a2` is a _local variable_.  Capturing `this` to get access to `a2` doesn't make any more sense than writing `this->a2` in the main body of the `foo::A()` function would make.

Comment: @Brian, quick question, does `a2` have to be captured by reference? Would `[this, a2]` work in this case?

Comment: @YingXiong capturing by value should be fine too.